# Is it a strong requirement to use vocative in Ukrainian language?

Tags: orthography, non-native-speaker, відмінювання, кличний-відмінок

I learned that the vocative should always be used and that it is not optional. I also assumed that all native Ukrainian speakers use the vocative in their normal, natural, everyday speech.

However, rather often in conversations with Ukrainians, I notice that vocative is omitted.

Please help me to understand how to use or not to use vocative?

Comment: unlike in Polish where it's getting obsolete de-facto, it's a thing in Ukrainian which just can not be ignored.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To cut a long story short: yes, it is obligatory when you address someone.

It is hard to prove that some case is as normal as any other, but in ["Правопис"](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par53) you'll find no notes about vocative case being optional.

As for why some people don't use it: there are a lot of native Russian-speakers in Ukraine and, unfortunately, not all of them learn Ukrainian thouroughly, and in Russian language there is no vocative case (see update). Under influence of Russian even some native Ukrainan speakers omit vocative case sometimes. So it is just a common mistake to omit vocative case.

Your Ukrainian will sound better if you don't omit vocative case, and it will never sound odd when you address someone.

**Update**: As @Serhii mentioned, there is some form of vocative case in Russian. But it is MUCH less common then in Ukrainian and exclusively in informal speaking. If you want to learn more, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case#Russian).

Answer (score 4):

As long as the Vocative case is stipulated by Ukrainian Orthography (Український правопис), it is obligatory.

When I went to school, vocative was taught as vocative "form" and not the vocative "case".

To the best of my awareness vocative was confirmed by Ukrainian Orthography (Український правопис) only in early nineties (in 1993 if I remember correctly).
Perhaps to enforce its obligatoriness not least of all.

Vocative *case* officially replaced the vocative *form* in 1990. Quoting [this article](http://refdb.ru/look/1449415.html):

> "Лише у третьому виданні “Українського правопису” (1990 р.) клична форма офіційно набула статусу відмінка. З цього часу у граматиках сучасної української мови стали виділяти сім відмінків: називний, родовий, давальний, знахідний, орудний, місцевий, кличний [2, c.21; 19, c.205]."
>
> Only in the third edition of Ukrainian Orthography (1990) vocative form was formally granted with the status of vocative case. Since then in modern Ukrainian grammar books seven cases have been differentiated: Nominative case, Genitive case, Dative case, Accusative case, Instrumental case, Locative case, **Vocative case** [2, p.21; 19, p.205].

Answer (score 2):

**Vocatives [always](http://posibnyky.vntu.edu.ua/u_m/1.htm) should be used in Ukrainian.** After moving from Russian to Ukrainian it seemed hard for me to use it first.

**Here's why**: there's no such case in modern Russian language (was used previously) so due to russification of Ukraine this case could be omitted but it shouldn't.

There are different rules for using vocatives in Ukrainian, you can them in [Wiki-page](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) as well as history terms.

Answer (score -1):

It is absolutely normal to use vocative in everyday speech as well as in official conversations. It makes your Ukrainian sound natural, as this form of the word is somehow distinctive for the language.

You can find some proper rules of the usage [here](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=405.0) (it is a forum thread abut usage of vocative and why it is good to use it) and [here](http://znoclub.com/mova-ta-literatura/554-vzhivannya-klichnogo-vidminka.html):

> ### Закінчення  –е у іменників, характеристиками яких є
>
> 1. Чоловічий або жіночий рід із закінченням –я, яке слугує пом’якшенням попереднього приголосного.
>
> Наприклад: Катруся - Катрусе, лисиця - лисице, скриня -скрине.
>
> 2. Жіночий рід із закінченням –а, але перед ним має бути шиплячий звук.
>
> Наприклад: криша - крише, чаша - чаше, листоноша - листоноше.
>
> 3. Чоловічий рід із нульовим закінченням або закінченням –о, перед яким знаходиться твердий приголосний основи слова.
>
> Наприклад: Євген – Євгене, Іван – Іване, козак – козаче.
>
> 4. Чоловічий рід мішаної групи, які закінчуються на –р. Це мають бути загальні назви, часто – рід діяльності.
>
> Наприклад: пісняр – пісняре, столяр – столяре, каменяр – каменяре.
>
> ### Закінчення  –є у іменників, характеристиками яких є
>
> Жіночий рід, особові імена та загальні назви, що закінчуються на –я,
>   яке йде після голосного звука.
>
> Наприклад, Марія – Маріє, Надія – Надіє, колія – коліє.
>
> ### Закінчення –о у іменників, характеристиками яких є:
>
> Чоловічий та жіночий рід, що мають закінчення -а.
>
> Наприклад, Олександра - Олександро, сестра - сестро, зірка - зірко.
>
> ### Закінчення  –у у іменників, характеристиками яких є
>
> 1. Чоловічий рід, у більшості односкладові, що мають тверді приголосні основи перед закінченням – о або нульовим закінченням.
>
> Наприклад, тато – тату, кран – крану, хліб –хлібу.
>
> 2. Чоловічий рід, що мають суфікси –к, -ик, -ок як вираження пестливого значення, та суфікси – ач, -ник.
>
> Наприклад, ведмедик – ведмедику, слухач – слухачу, керівник –
>   керівнику.
>
> 3. Чоловічі імена, що закінчуються на –х та –г.
>
> Наприклад,  Генріх – Генріху, Олег – Олегу, Людвіг – Людвігу.
>
> ### Закінчення  –ю у іменників, характеристиками яких є
>
> 1. Жіночий рід і закінченням –я, яке пом’якшує попередній приголосний та позначає пестливість.
>
> Наприклад, доня – доню, бабуся – бабусю, кицюня – кицюню.
>
> 2. Чоловічий рід із м’яким кінцевим приголосним основи, які також позначають пестливість.
>
> Наприклад, красень – красеню, татусь – татусю, дідусь – дідусю.
>
> 3. Жіночі та чоловічі імена із закінченням –я пестливої форми.
>
> Наприклад, Христя – Христю, Костя – Костю, Таня – Таню.
>
> 4. Чоловічий рід, що закінчуються на –й.
>
> Наприклад, водій – водію, каравай – караваю, гай – гаю.
>
> 5. Чоловічі імена з м’яким приголосним основи наприкінці.
>
> Наприклад, Юрій – Юрію, Василь – Василю, Олексій – Олексію.
>
> 6. Чоловічий рід, що має суфікси –ець, -ань, ень, - тель, -аль.
>
> Наприклад, молодець – молодцю, учень – учню, спасатель – спасателю.
>
> 7. Чоловічий рід, м’яка група із закінченням –р.
>
> Наприклад, Ігор – Ігорю, календар – календарю, лікар – лікарю.

Unfortunately. lots of people simplify the daily conversation, that's why you may not heard it, but I would recommend no do it if you want your Ukrainian sound natural and like a melody.

Comment: -1: Sorry, but this post does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @bytebuster, well, I guess the OP wants to hear about the usage of the vocative. Obviously, you should do it. In oral and written conversation. I have provided some links, which can help with the rules. On the forum people discuss the necessity of usage.

Comment: Your post answers the question, "how the Vocative is formed?", but the OP asks *whether or not they have to use it* in their speech, or just use the Nominative. Also, links do not help much; you should probably remove the superfluous quote and focus on answering the very question. And only keep the links that explain the necessity of the usage.